# error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘cv::MatCommaInit ializer_<float>’)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

the following error was encountered during compilation. Why does the pointer reference not work here?

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘cv::MatCommaInit
ializer_<float>’)
     KF.transitionMatrix = *(Mat_<float>(6, 6) <<
```

Code snippet:

```
void Tracking::kalman_xyz_init()
{
    const int stateNum = 6;
    const int measureNum = 3;
    KF = KalmanFilter(stateNum, measureNum, 0);
    state = cv::Mat(stateNum, 1, CV_32FC1); //state(x,y,z, detaX,detaY,detaZ)

    measurement = Mat::zeros(measureNum, 1, CV_32F);
    prediction = Mat::zeros(measureNum, 1, CV_32F);
    randn( state, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(0.1) );
    KF.transitionMatrix = *(Mat_<float>(6, 6) <<
                            1,0,0,1,0,0,
                            0,1,0,0,1,0,
                            0,0,1,0,0,1,
                            0,0,0,1,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,1,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,1  );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should tag your question with the names of the libraries you're using.

Comment: `Mat_<float>(6, 6)` is not a pointer, so you cannot use `*` to find what it points to, Just drop the `*`.